# Thredpoolexecutor with one worker & as_completed

Tags: python, threadpool, concurrent.futures

In general [concurrent.futures.as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed) does not return the input futures in the same order. What about the following special case though:

1. All futures are created by the same Executor instance.
2. The Executor has a single worker thread.

Is it guaranteed that the input order in this case is preserved? If not, why not ? A reproducible example would help.

Comment: The documentation doesn't make any guarantees, but looking at the implementation, it appears futures that complete before `as_completed()` is called are yielded based on their `id`, and then the remaining futures are yielded in the order they are completed.